# how to add a file and integer value to a File field and Integer field respectively

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm currently trying to make a form that adds the value to the "SampleField" model that I created but it seems to not go through. I made a form that should allow the user to put any integer value and a file it should add to the model. Can anyone point me to the right direction on what to do? Any help is appreciated.

Here is my forms.py

```
class SampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    timefile = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput)
    sample_fre = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput)

    class Meta:
        model = SampleField
        fields = ('timefile',)
```

Model.py

```
class SampleField(models.Model):
    timefile = models.FileField(upload_to="media/")
    sampling_frequency = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
```

views.py

```
def sample(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SampleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            file_uploaded = form.save(commit=False)
            file_uploaded.SampleField += form.sample_fre
            form.save()
            return redirect("<h1>Data saved Successfully<h1>")
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            form = SampleForm()
        return render (request, 'visual/value.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: And what is the line `file_uploaded.SampleField += form.sample_fre` supposed to do? `file_uploaded` is an instance of `SampleField` which has no attribute `SampleField` (it is the class of the `file_uploaded` variable).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I thought of something to get the integer value with the file which is wrong so could you suggest me the changes that must be done.. i just refferd to this question here in stack overflow [How to add integer to a integer Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842788/how-to-add-a-value-to-an-integer-field-via-a-form-in-django), but didnt find out how to add a file tho.

Comment: @ManojShivaprakash Did you mean `file_uploaded. sampling_frequency = form.sample_fre` to update `sampling_frequency`? [Check out the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)